# Unable to reach Object from void - C#

Tags: c#, object

I've currently got this code:

```
class CmdSets
{
        Object SQLObject = new SqlConnection("Data Source = {SourceRemoved}; user id={UserRemoved}; password={Removed}; Initial Catalog = Testing;");

        public void Test()
        {

            this.SQLObject.Open();
        }
```

I am unable to communicate with the object defined out of the void, the option which I have been using prior to this was to define the SQLObject in every member method, this is extremely redundant and requires a lot of hard coding to change credentials. Is there methods which will allow me to contact this object created?

Error Message Encountered:

> Error 1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Open' and no
>   extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of type 'object'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\SQLQueryCmdSet\CmdSets.cs    17  28  SQLQueryCmdSet

Comment: `Unable to reach Object.` What error is it giving.? It should work.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Sorry about missing out the message. please see the updated question body

Comment: Define `SQLObject` as `SqlConnection` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're downcasting to `Object`?

Comment: @lc. Recently picked up C# as a secondary language, under assumption from previous languages, I would have considered this to be an object so trying to "downcast" to the object seemed relevant as I am trying to create a new instance of SQLConnection

Comment: I wonder if you had in mind the `var` keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using Object? You should declare it as SqlConnection

```
SqlConnection SQLObject = new SqlConnection("Data Source = {SourceRemoved}; user id={UserRemoved}; password={Removed}; Initial Catalog = Testing;");
```

Comment: @marceln You're right, I realized it after I posted the answer

Comment: Is this not a object which I am initializing?  But just tried this and it seemed to work. The question remains to be clarified, is this not an object?

Comment: @DarylGill - in .Net *everything* is an object. So you're free to be as specific about what *kind* of object, as you want and/or need.

Comment: @Corak So, what' the difference between `(object)` & `(SqlConnection)` In this scenario?

Comment: @Corak except value types

Comment: @DarylGill It is an object, one of type `SqlConnection`. `System.Object` (or `object`) is actually a type - the base class everything ultimately inherits from.

Comment: @DarylGill - well, that taps into a pretty deep well. You might want to start with [Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173104.aspx) and go from there.

Comment: @clcto - don't value types also inherit from `System.Object`? That's how i read the graphic in [Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173104.aspx).

Comment: @Corak I guess you're right. primitives behave differently but can be boxed to value types.

Answer (score 3):

Create an instance of `SQLConnection` class instead of `object` class.

```
SQLConnection SQLObject = new SqlConnection("Data Source = {SourceRemoved}; user id={UserRemoved}; password={Removed}; Initial Catalog = Testing;");
```

When you make it an object, only object methods are available. Hence the error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Open'`

Comment: OK, but `boxing` is a concept that refers to converting value types to `Object`. This is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that you can't 'contact' the object, you are referencing it just fine.  But what you're asking it to do doesn't exist for something of type object.

You have a couple options.

First, don't make it type object.

Change your variable declaration to to following:

```
SqlConnection SQLObject = new SqlConnection("Data Source = {SourceRemoved}; user id={UserRemoved}; password={Removed}; Initial Catalog = Testing;");
```

This gives you access to all of the methods and properties of the type you actually want, whereas object has none of them.

Second, if for some reason you need to keep it as an object, cast the object as a SqlConnection before referencing methods or properties.

```
(SqlConnection)(this.SQLObject).Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the object when used:

`((SQLConnection) SQLObject).Open();`

Comment: No. Don't declare it as an object.

Comment: @clcto I agree, But I am answering his question: if one wants a compiler to understand the actual instance one has to cast.